# {Response: "False", Error: "Incorrect IMDb ID."}

Tags: reactjs

I've been trying to create a movie db api using  react with imdb api key. But When I try to click any of the movies that are displayed I get this error {Response: "False", Error: "Incorrect IMDb ID."}. I have an imdb key. Here is some of my code.

```
import React from 'react'

function Result({ result, openPopup }) {
return (
    <div className="result" onClick={() 
=> openPopup(result.imdbID)
}>
        <img src={result.Poster} />
        <h3>{result.Title}</h3>

    </div >
 )
 }

 export default Result
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I added wrong key in the api key. I removed the key and it worked